# I want to flash my app screen on android tv periodically

Tags: android, android-tv

So here is what I am trying to do, I have a doctor friend who has an android TV in his office. He would like to have a way to display the patients waiting list on that TV, automatically switching back and forth from the TV to the patient list periodically. I am planning on making a TV app with a compatible Phone app to allow generation and display of the patient list. But I have zero idea about how I might accomplish the switching from TV to app or is it even possible.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You wont be able to do this, newer android versions prevent you from starting activities from the background

Comment: Ok i will check. Although I am guessing there should be something like notifications or toasts that should be possible currently working on that assumption anyway. I will update here once i know more

Comment: Yeah you can do a notification for sure but to completely start a new activity without user interaction cannot be done

Comment: Ok thanks, I will check that out